# How to Match two comboboxes items together

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I’ve two comboboxes which should contain two different informations.

1.cb1: select table_name from information_schema.tables (this display multiple tables)
2.cb2: should populate it with a column name.

Example: I've three tables in cb1 with the same attributes but have different values at the column `EmpName` (tblLondon,tblBerlin,tblRom,...)

Now I wanna display in second comboboxe the column EmpName dynamically whenever I choose a table in first combobox.

```
cb1[tblLondon]                          cb2[John,Mavis,Chris,Mike..]
```

OR

```
cb1[tblBerlin]                          cb2[Günther,Peter, Sophie,Sunny, ..]
```

Can u plz help me out

```
string C = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(C);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC");
        try
        {
            // Open connection, Save the results in the DT and execute the spProc & fill it in the DT
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            cbTbl.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            cbTbl.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            //Fill combobox with data in DT
            cbTbl.DataSource = dt;
            // Empty bzw. clear the combobox
            cbTbl.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

This code is working and populating my cb1 (combobox)

And now i don't really know how to go about with cb2

```
 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to look into the [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: I assume you are using information_schema.tables because you don't know all the tables at design time?

Comment: I'm using that because i wanna be able to dynamically change table name anytime

Comment: As i understand,You just want to populate combobox2 based on combobox1 ? if that so,not need to set cb2's event  only cbtbl's event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, and if you have this data in SQL server or other database you should use `SelectedIndexChange` event and load item for that Id (use Display Member and Value Member for match Id).

take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).it might help you

Edit :
you can do this with below code : (if you don't use database)
you should use this code in cb1.SelectedIndexChange (or value)

```
        var cb2items = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "Name"}, {1, "anotherName"},{2,"Name"},{2, "anotherName"}}; // use the number for parent Id in cb1
        foreach (var item in cb2items)
        {
            if (item.Key == int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Edit 2 :

use this code in cb1.SelectedValueChange:

```
string C = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(C);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT ... WHERE TableName = cb1.SelectedValue");
      spProc & fill it in the DT
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        cbTbl.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        cbTbl.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        cbTb2.DataSource = dt;
```

and you also can create a procedure that send back the items from table name as input. if you use procedure, your code perform better.

Edit 3 :

put this code in `cbTb2.SelectedValueChange` event :

```
        try
        {
            int a = int.Parse(cbTB2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: Thnx but I'm using sql server to populate cb1. help?

Comment: I change the code , but because I don't know your database fields, I can't complete the query.

Comment: Thannx very much I'm gonna try my luck :)

Comment: This codes should work correctly, and you should try to change the sample code in answers to what you need. The answer can't completely be what you want.

Comment: Hi Pedram, 
 the code wasn't working right so i edited it a lil bit. The good thing is that it populating cb2 BUT with System.Data.Data RowView and i have no idea. Could u plz take a look?

Comment: if (cbTbl.SelectedValue != null)
 {
 string C = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(C);
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.CommandText = (" SELECT [Projektdefinition DB] FROM " + cbTbl.SelectedValue.ToString() + "");
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
try
{
con.Open();
dt = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dt);
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
con.Close();
}

Comment: It fill with this because you don't set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. and also if It doesn't solve, see edit 3

Comment: Ok. Thnx i have already tried it with dispaly & value member :
To the new member values ​​can not be bound. Parameter name is value.

Edit 3?

Comment: I don't understand. If you put display and value member **After that** you fill the combobox, it should work correctly. does it work ?

Comment: I also don't understand 
Yes i did exactly that but it isn't although the values are in the datatable. Very frustrating

Comment: It is so clear. It doesn't math to database item because **you forgot the `WHERE` in your query**. use where in the query to match items

Comment: Ok. i will try and if not i come back to u. Thanks for ur patience

Comment: sqlCmd.CommandText = ("SELECT DISTINCT [Projektdefinition] FROM " + ((DataRowView)cbTbl.SelectedItem).Row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + " WHERE [ Geschäftsbereich] = 'AB' AND  [Projektdefinition] = comboBox1.SelectedValue");

That was my try without success

Comment: Wazup Pedram i' ve solve it.
I really realy realy thank u very much.

Would be glad if u can help next time. God bless u

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see combobox's events, "SelectedIndexChanged" or "SelectedValueChanged" should do it

Comment: Hi
I'm new to c# winforms. where shd i apply the selectedindex changed so that cb2 will be populated. Would be new if u give me an example

Comment: Thnx but I still don't get it. I' m using sql server to populate cb1
So if a table there is selected, a defined column name should populate cb2. Is that possible?

Comment: yes,for every table name selected,get the combobox1 item text(tablename) and try do sql request again to get all the column name and add it in the combobox2 --simplest logic